# Multi file upload

Tags: javascript, ajax-upload

```
<?php $uploadNeed=3 ; for($i=0;$i<$uploadNeed;$i++) { ?>
    <div class="smWidth">
        <input type="file" name="upload_file" value="" id=" " OnClick="alert("
        2 ");" />
        <br />
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

I am able to create three file upload fields, but i want to add a new input file filed only when i select a file.... it should keep on increasing.... something like Facebook style file upload where you select a file for the first field, then the next popup's...

I am actually checking for click event of browse, but it does not work...

Comment: This is a javascript question... and will retag it as such

Comment: Have a look at [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) which has a nice multiple file-upload-feature included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very basic pure-JS implementation - hopefully it will give you a nudge in the right direction...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  // This keeps track of how many inputs there are, because each one MUST have a unique name!
  var inputCounter = 1;

  function inputChange() {

    // This function will add a new input element, in a div, as it is in your
    // original code, every time it is called. We attach it to the onchange
    // event of all the inputs

    // Declare local variables and increment input counter (for input names)
    var newContainerDiv, newClearDiv, newInput, newBr;
    inputCounter++;

    // Create the new elements and set their properties
    newContainerDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newContainerDiv.className = 'smWidth';
    newInput = document.createElement('input');
    newInput.type = 'file';
    newInput.name = 'upload_file_'+inputCounter;
    newInput.onchange = inputChange;
    newBr = document.createElement('br');
    newClearDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newClearDiv.className = 'clear';

    // Add the new elements to the DOM
    newContainerDiv.appendChild(newInput);
    newContainerDiv.appendChild(newBr);
    newContainerDiv.appendChild(newClearDiv);
    document.getElementById('uploads_container').appendChild(newContainerDiv);

  }

</script>

<!-- just create one input at first, so we don't need the PHP loop any more -->

<div id="uploads_container">
  <!-- we wrap it all in an outer container div with an id, to ease the task of adding more elements -->
  <div class="smWidth">
    <input type="file" name="upload_file_1" onchange="inputChange();" />
    <br />
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try hooking some other events to your file field. As far as I know, jQuery has a very useful event called .change()

I think that would work in your case.